# setting up App Push Notification entitlement with Distribution and Sandbox in Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, apple-push-notifications, xcode8.2

For push notification I turned on under **Capability** like following image in Xcode 8.2.1

[image: Capability]

after I turned on, Xcode created a **Entitlements File** inside the project folder. When I checked it has **APS Environment** with string `development`.

[image: Entitlements File]

The Push Notification is working fine in development/sandbox mode. How about Distribution/Production? Do I need to change the value of APS Environment into `distribution`? Or by Xcode itself the string value will be change automatically?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if your push notification working on development in sandbox mode then you have done all things.

Secondly, if you want to make this for Distribution, then you have to create certificates for Distribution too, Bellow image may help you.

[image]

This Image contains only distribution certificate for the app.

The production one must have to be created for the Pushnotification for working in live,

Like bellow Image

[image]

When you done with your production certificate and all,

then you have to create the AdHoc certificate for testing the notification or create the certificate for uploading the app in itunes.

When you creates Distribution certificate for AdHoc or Live, and double clicking on that, it will appear on the desired project and it will automatically handle the Capability, you don't have to worry about it, Also in your php code, you must change the link contain sandbox to apple. (i.e [ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195](http://ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195))

Thanks

Comment: thanks for your response, the required certificates already created and working fine with Xcode 7.3 in both mode. Now I upgraded Xcode into 8.2.1, in this I'm not receiving push notification 1st time. Then I updated push notification handling for iOS 10 SDK's like as per my questions. Now my question is,  **Do I need to change the value of APS Environment into `distribution` when uploading to store?** The Entitlements File is created by Xcode with above mentioned image in the question.

Comment: No, You don't need to create/change manually the APS Environment, it should be handled according to your certificate for Capability.

Comment: Definitely, When you done, test yourself by making adhoc through distribution. and don't forget to change the ssl gateway. Thank You.